# Apache POI conditional formatting search for string starts with some text

Tags: java, apache-poi, conditional-formatting

How can I create a conditional formatting rule for searching all content in the specified range that starts with some text?

I can create a rule that searches all content in the specified range that equals to some text.

```
 XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
 XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting sheet1cf = sheet1.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
 XSSFConditionalFormattingRule aRule = sheet1cf.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.EQUAL,"\"a\"");
//that search value="a"
```

However, I cannot figure out how to create a rule for searching all content in the specified range that starts with some text?

I am using Excel 2007.
I am using the following steps to create the rule.

1. Click conditional formatting drop down
2. Select "new rule"
3. Select "Format only cells that contain" in "Select rule type"
4. In "Format only cells", select "Specific Text" in the first drop down box
5. Select "contains" in the second drop down box
6. In my example, enter "a" in the third drop down box

Finally, set the background colour for the cells that contain "a".

Comment: How would you do this using `Excel`? `Apache poi` is not able to do what `Excel` cannot do. So we would need a [ConditionalFormattingRule based on a formula](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/SheetConditionalFormatting.html#createConditionalFormattingRule-java.lang.String-) like `(LEFT(INDEX($1:$1000,ROW(),COLUMN()),3)="bla")`.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are two different answers to this question.

**First: You wants using `XSSF` only and having exactly the same as `Excel` does according your description.**

Then we need using the low level underlying Objects of `apache poi` since `apache poi` dos not support [ComparisonOperator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ComparisonOperator.html) `BEGINS_WITH` although there is `STConditionalFormattingOperator.BEGINS_WITH`.

So we need at first creating a conditional formatting rule having any dummy `ComparisonOperator` and any dummy formula. Then we can replace those dummys with `STConditionalFormattingOperator.BEGINS_WITH` and a proper formula.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class XSSFConditionalFormattingBeginsWith {

 static XSSFConditionalFormattingRule createConditionalFormattingRuleBeginsWith(
         XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF, 
         String text) throws Exception {

  XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(
   ComparisonOperator.EQUAL /*only dummy*/, 
   "" /*only dummy*/);

  Field _cfRule = XSSFConditionalFormattingRule.class.getDeclaredField("_cfRule");
  _cfRule.setAccessible(true); 
  CTCfRule ctCfRule  = (CTCfRule)_cfRule.get(rule); 
  ctCfRule.setType(STCfType.BEGINS_WITH);
  ctCfRule.setOperator(STConditionalFormattingOperator.BEGINS_WITH);
  ctCfRule.setText(text);
  ctCfRule.addFormula("(LEFT(INDEX($1:$1048576, ROW(), COLUMN())," + text.length() + ")=\""+ text + "\")");
  _cfRule.set(rule, ctCfRule);

  return rule;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");

  XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
  XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule = createConditionalFormattingRuleBeginsWith(sheetCF, "bla");

  PatternFormatting fill = rule.createPatternFormatting();
  fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);
  fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

  XSSFConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new XSSFConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule};

  CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:B1000")};

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("XSSFConditionalFormattingBeginsWith.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

---

**Second: You wants using high level classes of `apache poi` and having both `HSSF` and `XSSF` supported.**

Then we only can use conditional formatting rule based on a formula. Excel itself supports this also by selecting [Use a formula to determine which cells to format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) in step 3 of your described process.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ConditionalFormattingBeginsWith {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");
  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

  String text = "bla";
  int lastRow = 1000;

  ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(
   "(LEFT(INDEX($1:$" + lastRow + ",ROW(),COLUMN())," + text.length() + ")=\"" + text + "\")");

  PatternFormatting fill = rule.createPatternFormatting();
  fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);
  fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

  ConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new ConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule};

  CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:B" + lastRow)};

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);

  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ConditionalFormattingBeginsWith.xlsx"));
  } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ConditionalFormattingBeginsWith.xls"));
  }
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: I use the second solution,  however, I use "search()" excel function to do so.

Comment: @The KNVB: Yes that's also an advantage of the formula conditional formatting rules. The formulas simply can be adjusted as needed. But I have answered your question which was "Apache POI conditional formatting search for string **starts** with some text". But for your information: There is `STConditionalFormattingOperator.CONTAINS_TEXT ` also.

Comment: @TheKNVB or Alex Richter can you share your formula as I'm trying to use SEARCH to find "-","+" and highlight row as such "SEARCH(\"-\";$F1)>=0" which is working in Excel directly but when I create one using sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("SEARCH(\"-\";$F1)>=0") its failing to applicate in LibreOffice and Excel even displays error for that.
In Libre when I edit rules and save (without changing thing) it starts to working again.
Much appreciate

Comment: @Mior: You are stuck with localization. Microsoft Excel **files** never are localized. Localization is done only in Excel GUI. So you nformula string must be `"SEARCH(\"-\",$F1)>=0"`. Note the comma instead of the semicolon.

Comment: Alex Richter you are the king, you get it right with so little information, it works, such a simple thing, Thanks a lot.